# How to Append a Div in-between two Divs based on their ID's using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript

If I have these objects:

```
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='2'></div>
<div id='3'></div>
<div id='4'></div>
<div id='5'></div>
```

I have a textbox:

```
<input type="text">
```

Where I type in the value: 3.5 to dynamically make (I have the code for this, the next part I need help with):

```
<div id='3.5'></div>
```

**How can I attach it in this order below, without first checking to see the value of every div on the page?**

```
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='2'></div>
<div id='3'></div>
<div id='3.5'></div>
<div id='4'></div>
<div id='5'></div>
```

Using:

```
$('#What Goes Here If I Dont know the elements on the page?').after('<div id='3.5'>Hey</div>');
```

Any help is appreciated,

Taylor

Comment: I don't think it's valid CSS to have IDs or Classes that begin with a number.

Comment: Why do you need sorted ID:s? Or why do you need ID:s at all? If you have a containing div with an id (or class) you can access its child elements in order.

Comment: Yes i am sorry for the ID in my example being a number, I only wrote that for the purposes of this example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IDs in the DOM should **not** start with a number (they would not be valid).
They should start with a character `A-Za-z` and then they can have numbers, `-` and `_` following.

but if you want to go your route try this:

```
var div = $("<div id='3.5'></div>");
div_id_after = Math.floor(parseFloat(div.get(0).id));

$('#'+div_id_after).after(div);
```

Here is a fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/DPMV5/

Comment: I know i'm sorry, for then purposes of this example I wanted to make it simple, I will of course take into account the rules for IDs

Comment: @TaylorMac, see my update, making a fiddle now (which jsfiddle is not loading at the moment)

Comment: Awesome. That would be great, I have never seen the use of parseFloat before

Comment: @Neal: I'm glad to hear that it's not just me that JS Fiddle's being slow for, this evening...

Comment: @Neal, I know. JS Fiddle's been struggling all evening for some reason. It's maybe just very, very popular these days?

Comment: @Taylor, fiddle is up on answer

Comment: Yes jsfiddle is not behaving for me as well. Maybe the guys that hacked Sony are turning to smaller projects haha

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with this ?

```
  $('#3').after('<div id='3.5'>Hey</div>');
```

Comment: He wants to dynamically find the div that he should insert after.

Comment: @Neal, I did.  Quite an inventive solution :)

Comment: Yes, I type in the ID, so there would be no way to use this function to attach it to the correct location because the $('#3') is already defined

Answer (score 1):

Firstly IDs aren't allowed to start with a number.

Ignoring that, if you are only allowing integers, it's easy, just take 1 from the value and insert it, then renumber the rest. Otherwise you'll have to walk the DOM to check the values of the others first.

Answer (score 0):

that comparision to add is arithmetic, so unfortunelly you need to iterate over the divs you could do this. maybe you should do padding, like 3 = 300000, so 3.5 is 3500000, to do a best comparision.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that would work:

```
var text = yourTextBox.value;
if(var number = Number(text))
{
    $('#'+Math.floor(number)).after('<div id='+text+'>Hey</div>');
} 
else alert("wrong number");
```

But you should probably check first (with a regex) that the text within the textbox is a legitimate number…

Answer (score 0):

updated. thanks Neal.

http://jsfiddle.net/FB8xG/3/

```
var newValue = 3.5;

var oldValue = Math.floor(newValue); //3

var oldValueID = ('#' + oldValue);
var newValueID = ('<div id="' + newValue + '">' + newValue + '</div>');

$(oldValueID).after(newValueID);
```

Comment: you can do: `var oldValue = Math.floor(newValue); //3`

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3T5pL/1/)**

```
var input = "3.5";
var parent = Math.floor(input);
var dest = $('#div-'+parent);

dest.after(dest.clone().attr('id','div-'+input).text(input));
```

**Note:** This will only work once between integers. A more robust method DOES require looking at the IDs of all divs within the destination.